# How to show different content?

Tags: android, settings

I have created two Android app's (soundboards). One version is normal, other one is censored. Now I want to squeeze them to only one app. Now, how to make an options in settings menu, to show, or not to show censored content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) with a [CheckBoxPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html) to your Application (don't forget to use the Manifest to declare them).

There is a nice sample of that in the [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/preference/index.html).

After doing that you can easily check a boolean value from the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) - here's how: [Data Storage Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).